# I need to validating a 9 similar-digit numbers

Tags: php, regex, html

how can I create pattern to verify that this number doesn't happen in my text input in php

```
000000000
111111111
222222222
333333333
444444444
555555555
666666666
777777777
888888888
999999999
```

Comment: Are these numbers stings or integers? Will there always be 9 characters/digits or are you trying to stop a repetition of those digits and do you want to avoid 9999 as well?

Comment: this numbers are Intergers

Answer (score 0):

It's like:

```
if(preg_match('/\d{9,}/', $input)){ // 9 or more digits
  echo 'Problem';
}
else{
  echo 'No Problem';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following will search the entire string and if it contains the bad input, then it will not detect it, otherwise it will (per your request).

```
^((?!(\d)\1{7}).)*$
```

Regex101:

https://regex101.com/r/BLIBVW/3

PHP Example:

```
<?php

$testFail = "I like 111111111, but I can't use it";
echo preg_match('/^((?!(\d)\1{7}).)*$/', $testFail);

?>
```

Comment: It works until 5 but when I repeat 9 time 4 the validation doesn't worky why?

Comment: 9 four times works properly: https://regex101.com/r/BLIBVW/4 . It doesn't pass it because there isn't 9 characters.  If you could mark as solution, it'd help a lot.

Comment: What I want is when the user type 444444444 in my input text. When this happen I want my validation check that they can't do that. I hope this explain my idea better